# Creating a new project difference between application name and module name

Tags: android-studio

Android Studio 0.4.4

Hello,

I am using Android Studio and I am just wondering what is the difference between the Application name and module name when you create a new project.

Do they have to be the same name?

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is help text in the New Project dialog, at the bottom:

Application name: The application name is shown in the Play store, as well as in the Manage Applications list in settings.

Module name: This module name is only used by the IDE. It can typically be the same as the application name.

They don't have to be the same.